# Unable to get Twilio "call-recording" url

Tags: php, twilio

I am developing a `Twilio` based application for a online campaign management system, and for each campaign there will be a `twilio` number and a target number. Whenever somebody will call to a `twilio` number (assigned for a particular campaign), it will be forwarded to the particular target number. There are also two `Check-box` field (one for `Call-Whisper` and another for `Call-Recording`) for each campaign.

I got a reference for `Call-Whisper` and `Call-Recording` from :
 [Call Screening and Recording](http://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/ivrs-call-screening-and-recording)

But unable to understand how to get the call-recording url from this tutorial.

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio evangelist here.

You will need to add an `action` attribute to the `<Dial>` tag. This attribute takes a URL as a parameter, and once the call completes Twilio will make a request to that URL. That request will contain a paramater called `RecordingUrl`, which will have the URL of the recorded file. So configure the `<Dial action="">` to some URL on your server, and then you'll get the request so you can download/store the recording.

You can see more about this in the TwiML documentation for the [Dial](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial) verb.

Hope this helps!